# Utilize a ActionListener object from a separate JFrame class to main class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

I am building a GUI program in which specific code takes place when a certain condition is meant ***(JButton is pressed)***. I have a seperate class that constructs my Jframe called "MyFrame" .

Essentially I want to know the proper way to use my use a ActionListener/ ActionEvent from my "MyFrame" class in conjunction when a JButton is pressed in which it would correlate properly in the main class.

For example i am able to initiate specific code when a JButton is pressed in my MyFrame class through the actionPerformed provided method by java in my Myframe class,  I am just puzzled on how I can make the same thing work through my main class as well.

Any assistance would be appreciated

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame mf;

        mf= new MyFrame();
        Expenses exp ;
        BudgetSystem system ;
        ActionEvent e ;
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

 class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JFrame myFrame; 
    JPanel myPanel; 
    JLabel greetText ; 
    JButton addReportButton;
    JButton exitButton;

    ActionListener event ; 
    BorderLayout layout ; 

    MyFrame() {
        myFrame = new JFrame();
        myPanel = new JPanel();
        greetText = new JLabel();
        addReportButton = new JButton();
        exitButton = new JButton();

        myPanel.setBorder(null);
        myFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));
        greetText.setText("Please choose one of the following options to begin:" );
        myPanel.add(greetText);
        myFrame.add(myPanel);
        addReportButton.setText("Add a budget report");
        addReportButton.addActionListener(this);
        myPanel.add(addReportButton);
        exitButton.setText("Close Program");
        exitButton.addActionListener(this);
        myPanel.add(exitButton);
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        myFrame.pack();
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        /*
        if (e.getSource()==addReportButton)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame,"This button Works!");
        }
        else if (e.getSource()== dummyButton)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame,"This is the dummy button ! , you are targeting specific buttons now ! ... YOU ROCK :) ");
        }else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(myFrame,"This is does not work :( ");

         */
    }
}
```

I tried to make a specific ActionEvent object in main but that did not work properly.

I also tried to use a MyFrame object to access the actionPerformed method in java but that doesnt seem to work either.

Comment: Are you trying to pass an ActionListener *into* the MyFrame class? If so, then give the class a "setter" method that sets the listener, or an "adder" method that adds a listener.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to add listeners to a JButton from another class, one option is to give the class that holds the JButton a public method that allows this to happen, for instance:

```
public void addMyButtonListener(ActionListener listener) {
    myButton.addActionListener(listener);
}
```

This would allow any object that holds an instance of the class that holds the JButton to call this method and pass in a listener.

For instance:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class AddOutsideActionListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            SomeGUI mainPanel = new SomeGUI();
            mainPanel.addMyButtonListener(e -> {
                String message = "Message from the main method";
                String title = "Message";
                int type = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainPanel, message, title, type);
            });

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Some GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
```

```
class SomeGUI extends JPanel {
    public static final int PREF_W = 600;
    public static final int PREF_H = 400;
    private JButton myButton = new JButton("My Button");
    
    public SomeGUI() {
        add(myButton);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H));
    }
    
    public void addMyButtonListener(ActionListener listener) {
        myButton.addActionListener(listener);
    }
}
```